# Producing collapsible field sets with theme functions

Tags: 6

In an older Drupal 6 instance, I'm updating a module to produce a collapsible fieldset with the following:

```
function my_module_function($table_collections) {
    // include JavaScript for collapse functionality
    drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');

    foreach($table_collections as $table) {
            $to_return .= '<fieldset class="collapsible collapsed">';
            $to_return .= '<legend><span><a href="#">' . $title . '</a></span></legend><div>' ;
            $to_return .= theme_table(array_keys($table[0]), $table);
            $to_return .= '</div></fieldset>';
    }


    return $to_return;


}
```

My question, is there a better way to wrap this in a complete theme function? `theme_fieldset` and `ctools_collapsible_theme(&$items)` appears to be for forms. Is there a more standard or better approach than what I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call theme_fieldset() directly, even if it's not for a form, as long as you structure the $element correctly:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_fieldset/6

You can see an exemple in core here:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/theme_system_modules/6

```
$fieldset = array(
  '#title' => t($package),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => ($package == 'Core - required'),
  '#value' => theme('table', $header, $rows, array('class' => 'package')),
);
$output .= theme('fieldset', $fieldset);
```

theme_fieldset() is also valid in Drupal 7, but it seems to have changed in Drupal 8.